# Can't generate large heatmaps using highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts, heatmap

I am trying to use highcharts for large heatmap generation.I have tried to modify     [demo code given on highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas/) website.

As by default it sets date on x axis , I need to some other values then default data format on x-axis.I have followed few question on Stack overflow which gives me the required output but it's not correct as heatmaps does't seems right and when I hover on the result ,tooltip shows those date formats on hovering and generated heatmaps is also not correct.

```
My fiddle demo is:  http://jsfiddle.net/ktamk1tp/1/
```

Note: I am getting error in posting js fiddle link according to SO guidelines.It would be appreciated if anyone can edit this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling colsize in series helps - http://jsfiddle.net/ktamk1tp/9/

(JS line 255)

```
//colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix for your yAxis title is that you are setting it twice:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        enabled: true,

        // THIS Axis title is not working, but the same method works for the xAxis

        text: 'my axis'
    },
    categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
    title: null
},
```

Remove `title: null`.

The reason your tooltip looks odd is that you are setting your axis to categories using string integers and then converting to a date stamp. The conversion of xAxis = '0' to javascript time is correct. The 0 js time is Jan 1 1970. You need to either send in the javascript timestamp and set the axis accordingly or you need to use categories that are dates `['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday'....]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Tooltip issue was fixed by that but still heatmap is not correct as tooltip shows value value  for the z(3 r dparameter on basis of which coulours are filled in heatmap).Slider below shows correct color for that.But heatmap displays different color for that. Please have a look. url : http://jsfiddle.net/ktamk1tp/4/

Comment: As hovering over 0,4 shows value of 14.2 which should be red as slider below shows , but color value for it in heatmap is different.

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar it looks like you have other issues with your data format. For example you never have data for 0,3. You have 0-9 x elements and 0-6 y elements but you are setting them to be 0-9 for one and 0-4 for another in the category declaration. I think you have some transposition going on.

Comment: I tried editing that but still it does't work . fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ktamk1tp/6/ .I dont know much idea about javascript and heatmaps.Sorry for asking so  many questions and help

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar If I understand you correctly disabling colsize in series should help (JS line 255) [http://jsfiddle.net/ktamk1tp/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/ktamk1tp/9/)

Comment: @KacperMadej: Yeah .I fixed that .Can you make it an answer so I can approve it as answer. :)